# C# Создание экземпляра потомка по типу, определенному в базовом классе

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть базовый класс

```
public abstract class Session
{
    public abstract SessionType SessionType { get; }
}
```

И есть куча его наследников, возвращающих нужный тип SessionType.

Каждому типу строго соответствует один наследник.

Вопрос:

Как создать экземпляр нужного потомка зная тип.

ПС.
Понятно, что можно сделать метод по свичу создающий потомков. 
Но тогда при каждом создании нового типа нужно будет добавлять новую инициализацию объекта.
Можно ли это сделать более простым способом?

Comment: Как-то неправильно вы решаете задачу. Используйте Type вместо SessionType или заведите словарь, связывающий SessionType и Type.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще SessionType? Где он используется?

Comment: SessionType используется при обработке сессии, отображении данных, сохранения связанных данных (каждому типу соответствуют свои данные)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо за ответы. Оба ответа мне помогли.

Решил задачу немного другим способом, отличным от обоих предложенных.

Точнее, соединил их в одно решение.

Идея:

Для каждого класса-потомка устанавливается атрибут.

Потом сканируем потомков и определяем по атрибуту нужный тип

Создаем экземпляр.

Реализация:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestAttrib
{
    public enum SessionType
    {
            One
        ,   Two
    }
    public abstract class Session
    {
        public abstract SessionType SessionType { get; }

        public static Session construct(SessionType sessionType)
        {
            Type typeSession = typeof(Session);
            Type type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeSession).GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeSession)
                                                                                       && (t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SessionTypeAttribute)) as SessionTypeAttribute).SessionType == sessionType
                                                                                    );

            if (type != null)
            {
                return (Session)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    [SessionType(SessionType.One)]
    public class Session_One : Session
    {
        public override SessionType SessionType => SessionType.One;
    }

    [SessionType(SessionType.Two)]
    public class Session_Two : Session
    {
        public override SessionType SessionType => SessionType.Two;
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class SessionTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SessionTypeAttribute(SessionType sessionType)
        {
            SessionType = sessionType;
        }
        public SessionType SessionType { get; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Session.construct(SessionType.One).ToString());   //Выведет TestAttrib.Session_One
            Console.WriteLine(Session.construct(SessionType.Two).ToString());   //Выведет TestAttrib.Session_Two
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно сделать свой атрибут, через который вы будете устанавливать соответствие типов между `Session` и `SessionType`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SessionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SessionAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
    public Type Type { get; } 
}
```

Декорируем нашим атрибутом `SessionType`:

```
public class FirstSession : Session
{
    public override SessionType SessionType => new FirstSessionType();
}

public class SecondSession : Session
{
    public override SessionType SessionType => new SecondSessionType();
}    

[Session(typeof(FirstSession))]
public class FirstSessionType : SessionType { }

[Session(typeof(SecondSession))]
public class SecondSessionType : SessionType { }
```

После этого можно создать экземпляр `Session` зная `SessionType`:

```
public static Session CreateInstanceOfSession(Type sessionType)
{
    var attr = sessionType.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SessionAttribute)) as SessionAttribute;
    if (attr != null)
    {
        return (Session)Activator.CreateInstance(attr.Type);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Проверяем:

```
Console.WriteLine(CreateInstanceOfSession(typeof(FirstSessionType)).ToString()); //Выведет FirstSession
Console.WriteLine(CreateInstanceOfSession(typeof(SecondSessionType)).ToString()); //Выведет SecondSession
```

Comment: Тогда уж добавить абстрактное свойство в `SessionType`, чтоб уж всегда было.

Comment: @Zufir, Как по мне вариант со словарем еще лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, "более простым" способом это сделать нельзя. Но можно сделать более сложным.

Вы можете просканировать все ассембли процесса и собрать все типы, которые являются неабстрактными потомками `Session`. Потом создав инстанс каждого из этих типов и вызвав у него `SessionType`, заполните лукап таблицу для нахождения типа потомка `Session` по значению `SessionType`.

Comment: Можно привести пример более сложного способа?